# Berachot 4b - What's so special about an alphabetical acrostic?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, aleph-bet-letters, tractate-brachot, olam-haba-world-to-come

The Talmud in [Berachot 4b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=4b&format=pdf) states:

> אמר רבי אלעזר א"ר אבינא כל האומר תהלה לדוד בכל יום שלש פעמים מובטח לו שהוא בן העולם הבא מאי טעמא אילימא משום דאתיא באל"ף בי"ת נימא אשרי תמימי דרך דאתיא בתמניא אפין אלא משום דאית ביה פותח את ידך נימא הלל הגדול דכתיב ביה נותן לחם לכל בשר אלא משום דאית ביה תרתי
>
> R. Eleazar b. Abina says: Whoever recites [the psalm] Praise of David three times daily, is sure to inherit the world to come. What is the reason? Shall I say it is because it has an alphabetical arrangement? Then let him recite, Happy are they that are upright in the way, which has an eightfold alphabetical arrangement. Again, is it because it contains [the verse], Thou openest Thy hand [and satisfiest every living thing with favour]? Then let him recite the great Hallel, where it is written: Who giveth food to all flesh! — Rather, [the reason is] because it contains both.
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_4.html#PARTb))

What exactly is the value of an alphabetical acrostic such that the Talmud thinks that that is the reason why reciters of this psalm will be a person of the World to Come?

Comment: Starting up the old daf yomi challenge? Be"H I'll be joining you...if you don't keep stealing my questions :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, when anything is said to guarantee the world to come, this is not understood literally. It is obvious that someone cannot be a mass murderer and then recite Ashrei and be absolved. Rather, this statement should be understood as a proxy of sorts, that one who performs this praiseworthy action, which strengthens his faith, is likely to possess the traits required for the world to come.

With that understanding, we can begin to discuss why the acrostic is relevant. The Pnei Yehoshua posits that both the acrostic and the verse serve to reinforce the notion that God created the world for the sake of those who study the Torah. Here is the full piece. The bold parts are my addition. (If anyone knows of a translation, please feel free to edit)

> שם אמר ר"א אמר רבי אבינא כל האומר תהלה לדוד בכל יום ג"פ מובטח כו' **ונראה שהכוונה בזה שע"י שיאמר זה המזמור ג"פ בכוונת הלב בתלת זימני הוי חזקה ותתחזק האמונה האמיתית בלבו שכל העולם כולו לא נברא אלא לצוות לזה למי שעוסק בתורה שנתנה ע"י כ"ב אותיות הא"ב שיש בזה המזמור וכל הנבראים והנעשים לא נבראו אלא בשביל כך כנודע ויכוון ג"כ בפסוק פא"י ומשביע לכל חי שהקב"ה זן ומפרנס עולמו מקרני ראמים עד ביצי כנים וכולם מתפרנסים שלא ביגיעה ושלא בצער** וכדכתיב לעיל מיניה בזה המזמור עיני כל אליך ישברו ואתה נותן להם את אכלם בעתו א"כ בודאי החי יתן על לבו ויאמר למה זה הבל וריק איגע כל היום לעשות מלאכתי קבע לעסוק בצרכי פרנסה שמכיון שכל הנבראים שאינן אלא לצוותא בעלמא מזמן להם הקב"ה פרנסתן שלא ביגיעה כ"ש שראוי ונכון שיעשה כן לשומרי בריתו ולזוכרי פקודיו שהם עיקר ויסוד העולם שיזמן להם פרנסתן שלא ביגיעה. וכמאמר הכתוב השלך על ה' יהבך והוא יכלכלך ונאמר ג"כ לא ראיתי צדיק נעזב וגו'. נמצא שמתוך כך בודאי יעשה מלאכתו עראי ומלאכת שמים קבע כמ"ש חז"ל שכל העושה כך זה וזה נתקיים בידו. וזה שאמר מובטח לו שהוא בן ע"ה וק"ל. והשתא אתי נמי שפיר שתקנו חכמים לומר כל הג' פעמים ביום ולא בלילה סמוך לתפילת ערבית משום שעיקר יגיעות ועמל האדם במלאכתו הוא באותו זמן שאחר תפילת שחרית וכדכתיב יצא אדם לפעלו ולעבודתו עדי ערב. עד אחר תפלת המנחה כנ"ל:

Comment: But what if the mass murderer recites Ashrei 3 times a day?